# This Error is regarding the Add-Migration and update-Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-sql-database

I get this error:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: [0, Property: Bulky.Models1.ShoppingCart (Dictionary<string, object>).ProductId (no field, int?) Indexer FK]

Model class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bulky.Models1
{
    public class NewShoppingCart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        
        [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between 1 to 1000")]
        public int Count { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        [ValidateNever]        
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktkuL.png)

I am trying to create a table called `NewShoppingCart`, but I get this error during migration.

Comment: Could you share all the classes used in your application and data. Which approach have been used either Code First Approach or DB First Approach?

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` attribute can be put either on the "key with specific property name"  or "navigation property with specific key name"
It's like

```
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
```

or

```
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

Try following:

```
    public class NewShoppingCart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [ValidateNever]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between 1 to 1000")]
        public int Count { get; set; }


        [ValidateNever]
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Reference :https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx